# Why is the site Read-Only for me?

Tags: support

There was a maintenance window today apparently and AFAICT the maintenance was finished much earlier today. But I cannot e.g. post comments: it complains that the site is in read-only state - in many (but not in all) cases, the page thinks I'm logged out and asks me to login, but when I try I get the same error. That has been going on all day today.

Nevertheless, I see questions posted in the last few hours, so apparently it is *not* read-only for others. Anybody else have the same problem? If so, why are there two classes of users?

If nobody else has the problem, is there anything I can do to get out of read-only state? I've restarted Firefox a couple of times and I've tried Google Chrome as well to no avail.

PS: there seems to be a [second maintenance effort](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/b65c407c-6962-41dc-afac-f4d276b28e68), titled "FBB - Adjust Kubernetes Node Pools", going on which is marked `Started`, so it may be the cause of the problem. But it's still not clear to me why some people have access while others don't.

PPS: I don't see the problem on SO or on the Unix/Linux SE, but I do see it on Math SE and Physics SE as well.

Note (one day later): The site is no longer Read-Only for me. The status page still shows the "FBB - Adjust Kubernetes Node Pools" maintenance as started. I would still be interested to find out if my experience is "typical".